# Php mysql search script, how to make single searched words bold if the search term wasn't the exact match to my database entry

Tags: php, mysql, database

Below is my script so far. This displays the users search term in bold if it is an exact match. For example. if the user searched "john bloggs" then it would be returned bold. whereas if the user searched for "john" then it would show the john bloggs entry but it wouldnt be in bold. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<?
mysql_connect ("localhost", "user","pass")  or die (mysql_error());
mysql_select_db ("databasename");

$term = $_POST['term'];

$sql = mysql_query("select * from tablename where category like '%$term%' or title like '%$term%' or postcode like '%$term%' or info like '%$term%' ");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){

    echo '<br/> Category: '.str_replace($term,'<b>'.$term.'</b>',$row['category']);
    echo '<br/> Title:    '.str_replace($term,'<b>'.$term.'</b>',$row['title']);
    echo '<br/> Address:  '.$row['add1'];
    echo '<br/> Street:   '.$row['street'];
    echo '<br/> City:     '.$row['city'];
    echo '<br/> Postcode: '.str_replace($term,'<b>'.$term.'</b>',$row['postcode']);
    echo '<br/> Phone:    '.$row['phone'];
    echo '<br/> E-Mail:   '.$row['email'];
    echo '<br/> Website:  '.$row['website'];
    echo '<br/><br/>';

}
?>
```

Comment: hello, the problem is that i only get bold matched results if it is an exact match. so if someone typed "national health service" it would return in bold. whereas if someone typed "national" then it would return but not in bold. thanks

Comment: You could also create a small function to pass the term and $row in. So getTerm($term,$row['category']) where you function will return a string depending on if they are equal to not. Just a little easier to read. The other thing is, you are open to SQL injection.

Comment: BTW: in times of upcoming HTML5 you may use `<mark>search term</mark>` instead of `<b>`. See: http://html5doctor.com/draw-attention-with-mark/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using the following:

```
/**
 * higlights search string with HTML5-mark
 *
 * @param string needle search string
 * @param string haystack original text, may contain search string
 * @return string original text with additional HTML-mark highlighting
 */
function highlight($needle, $haystack)
{
    return preg_replace('/(' . preg_quote($needle, '/') . ')/i', '<mark>$1</mark>', $haystack);
}
```

Usage:

```
echo '<br/> Category: ' . highlight($term, $row['category']);
```

Comment: what will i need to edit in this code in order to use it please and what should i replace in my original code? thanks so much :)

Comment: got this error? any ideas why? thanks
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare highlight() (previously declared in /var/www/vhosts/askinfo.co.uk/httpdocs/search.php:107) in /var/www/vhosts/askinfo.co.uk/httpdocs/search.php on line 107

Comment: showed me one entry with the desired highlight affect though :D

Comment: @John Lord "Cannot redeclare highlight()" means, there is already a function called highlight somewhere in the application you use, or you are including the search.php twice (try include_once instead).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
echo '<br/> Category: '.($term == row['category'] ? '<b>'.$term.'</b>' : $row['category']);
```

Comment: Works fine for me?  I have updated the code example to be 100% clear.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem that you are facing is the %term% thing. On the database it will look up for any matched whatever the position the term is. So if you try to do a string replace "foo bar" it will search only for the matching string "foo bar" and not "foo" or "bar".

You can do the following
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
        $terms = explode(" ", $term);
        foreach ($terms as $wordToReplace)
        {
         $category = str_replace($wordToReplace,`'<b>'`.$wordToReplace.`'</b>'`,$row['category']);
         $title = str_replace($wordToReplace,`'<b>'`.$wordToReplace.`'</b>'`,$row['title']);
         $postCode = str_replace($wordToReplace,`'<b>'`.$wordToReplace.`'</b>'`,$row['postcode']);
        }
         // and then show it
        echo '
 Category: '.$category;
        echo '
 Title:    '.$title;
        echo '
 Address:  '.$row['add1'];
        echo '
 Street:   '.$row['street'];
        echo '
 City:     '.$row['city'];
        echo '
 Postcode: '.$postCode;
        echo '
 Phone:    '.$row['phone'];
        echo '
 E-Mail:   '.$row['email'];
        echo '
 Website:  '.$row['website'];
}

NOTE:This code was not tested!

Comment: code didnt work but you understand me completely by your response so if you could further help me in implementing this code it would be of great help to me. Thankyou!

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking for something quick and functional what you have should be fine.  If you wanted to improve it a bit you may want to use styles instead of the `<b>` tag and use PHP's [strcasecmp()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strcasecmp.php) function

For exmaple:

```
$field = (strcasecmp($term, $row['foo'])==0) ? "<span class='bold'>".$row['foo']."</span>" : $row['foo'];
```